# Finding class source in android project (LinkedBlockingDeque)

Tags: android, android-source

I'm looking for a class source added to the Android sdk in version 9. The class is `LinkedBlockingDeque`.
How do you go about finding the source for a particular class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 1.6 implementation.
Download it from [here](http://massapi.com/source/jdk1.6.0_17/src/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.java.html)

Then change

```
implements BlockingDeque<E>
```

to

```
implements BlockingQueue<E>
```

To make it compile on Android. BlockingDeque is sub interface of BlockingQueue, so no harm done.

Answer (score 0):

i don't think any of the above would help:
first, some of the licenses mentioned are not totally open source - surely he would prefer apache license.
second , about the android classes , i can't find this class there. it would probably be much better to get the code from there .

i think that for now , the best thing would be to implement it by yourself . even the naive solution of having a single lock could be enough , depending on your needs.